# Is it possible to increase the speed of this search and copy snippet?

Tags: powershell, search, copy

I've got this script to search through a remote server for specific files I've listed in a CSV. However the process is very slow and I'm wondering if it's my code that makes it so. Can I improve it somehow? I've thought that simply making a directory list and searching it for the files in my CSV might be faster to avoid recursively looking through every file.

```
$source = "\\server1\Scanning_Maps"
$destination = "\\server1\Transfer\TEST"

$searchFiles = Import-CSV 'C:\Users\user1\Desktop\test.csv' -Header ("filename")

ForEach($File in $searchFiles) 
{
    Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $File.filename } | Copy-Item -Destination $destination    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to do some testing but on top of jisaak's findings you can reduce this even further by only returning files you want to copy as supposed to all files and then post processing.

> I've thought that simply making a directory list and searching it for the files in my CSV might be faster to avoid recursively looking through every file.

Using `-Include` you can pass it the array of filenames and it should only search for and return the files that you want.

Also if you are adding the header anyway I going to guess that you have only a one column csv? If that is the case you don't even need to bother with that cmdlet and only use `Get-Content`.

```
$searchFiles = Get-Content 'C:\Users\user1\Desktop\test.csv'
```

If that is a CSV file and you are using header to just work the first column then ignore that tidbit. If it is a csv we should at least expand the column so you just have a string array instead of an object one.

```
$searchFiles = Import-CSV 'C:\Users\user1\Desktop\test.csv' -Header ("filename") | Select-Object -ExpandProperty filename
```

Now lets try using `-Include`. Note that it only works with `-Recurse` and might do nothing without it.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Include $searchFiles -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination $destination
```

There, no more foreach loop required. That should be even faster.

Answer (score 1):

You run the Get-ChildItem cmdlet for every file in `$searchFiles` you should put it outside the `foreach`loop:

```
$source = "\\server1\Scanning_Maps"
$destination = "\\server1\Transfer\TEST"

$searchFiles = Import-CSV 'C:\Users\user1\Desktop\test.csv' -Header ("filename")

$sourceList = Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse 

ForEach($File in $searchFiles) 
{
     $sourceList | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $File.filename } | Copy-Item -Destination $destination    
}
```

Comment: also, if the filepath in $File matches your local files, you could use Get-Item $File

Comment: thanks - can you explain to me the fundamental difference? I'm not so familiar with powershell and assumed that moving the Get-ChildItem cmdlet outside the loop wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Get-ChildItem will recursivly gather the files in `\\server1\Scanning_Maps` which probably can talke a while since its a shared drive. If you put it outside the foreach loop, the files will be gathered only once and stored in `$searchFiles`.